# Moving CodeIgniter To Another Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined-index

I am attempting to move a clients website to a new server, this website was built long before I started at my company by someone who has left. It is built using CodeIgniter which is something I have no experience with.

I transferred everything yesterday (Files and Mysql Database) and thought everything had gone well. Until today when I have noticed that trying to update any information in the database leads to Undefined Index Errors.

I have now changed back to the old server which has had no changes other than being linked to the database on the new server. But this is now having the same issues, even after setting it back to the original database as well.

Could this be something to do with the database?

Comment: Share some screen shot or site link . So that we can help u.

Comment: I've actually just managed to figure this out, the changes I made must have been picked up automatically and the mode was changed from "production" to "development" in index.php. The undefined index errors were always there looking back at logs, but just weren't being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the mode had somehow changed from "production" to "development" within the root index.php file. Updating this value corrected my issue.